# Upgrade Windows 7 RC using Retail Ultimate install DVD

Tags: windows-7, upgrade

I installed Windows 7 RC Ultimate on a friend's machine, and starting today her computer won't boot into Windows anymore. I'm not sure exactly what the problem is (waiting for her to bring her laptop over) but I know RC is about to expire around now. Anyone else seen this problem?

She has a Windows 7 RTM Ultimate retail DVD -- 2 questions:

1) any suggestions on how to upgrade without her losing her original data. I assume I can just boot with the install disc and choose "Upgrade" but don't know if it'll work. While I wait for her to come by, I was hoping someone could provide any guidance on what I should try.

2) Any ideas why the computer won't boot into Windows 7 RC? From what I read it should boot and then shut down every 2 hours (assume this isn't some other problem like a bad hard drive)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot upgrade the RC to RTM officially. This was made clear when you signed up for the testing program.

You can, however, [hack your way around it](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/3075/how-to-upgrade-the-windows-7-rc-to-rtm/)

Answer (score 2):

Your friend should have been receiving warnings for the last 2 weeks that the RC copy was about to expire - I was in a virtual machine that was running Win7 RC.

Upgrading is possible by hacking a file and rebuilding the ISO file or launching setup from the hard disc, like **[@taspeotis](https://superuser.com/questions/114659/upgrade-win7-rc-using-retail-ultimate-install-dvd/114663#114663)** says.

However, I think you would be better off installing Windows 7 RTM fresh. Using an external enclosure, you can copy all of the files from the harddrive to another computer, format and install Windows, and then copy the personal documents back.